# java.sql.SQLException : General error

Tags: java

This is my code:
 For insert the values into the database and display the value from the database

```
import java.sql.*;
    class DbEx{
        public static void main(String args[]) throws SQLException{
            try{
                Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
                Connection c=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:jaga","","");
                Statement s=c.createStatement();
                s.execute("INSERT INTO stud VALUES(2,'Nirmal',23,'Btech','Male',720043)");
                ResultSet rs=s.executeQuery("SELECT Id,Name FROM stud");
                while(rs.next()){
                System.out.println("ID"+rs.getInt(0)+"\nName"+rs.getString(1));
                }
                c.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println(e);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: catch `SQLException` not `Exception`

Comment: So what is the error you are seeing?

Comment: put the error message so we can help you, also change throws SQLException for chatch SQLException

Comment: Mention host in you conneciton line also create new statement for second query.